# Is it possible to use photoswipe with ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, photoswipe

I am trying to use a photoswipe gallery in angular, but it does not work if I try to add a custom button with ng-click on it. Please see an example with ng-click [here](http://aislynart.com/#/albums/Animals). Just open an image and click on the top-left custom button.

Comment: Have you tried to use an angular-photoswipe module like these?

- https://github.com/m00s/angular-photoswipe
- https://github.com/jsnmgpnty/angular-photoswipe

Comment: Not yet, that will be the next move if I do not manage to do it like this.